# Error: spawnSync /home/khaleefakt/khaleefakt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)

Tags: android, react-native

Actually i am first in react-native technology.
i followed react native getting started tutorial and getting to here.
after install every dependencies and trying to run-android getting this error.
[image: error while running npx react-native run-android]

and also app installed on my mobile and not working.